# How to pass variables from Joomla controller to a model?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have tried to find info about it. still no way to do it, any idea how to do it?

p.s. I work on Joomla 2.5 creating an MVC component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this something like this .

```
$model = $this->getModel('mymodel');
$item=$model->filterSection($variable);
```

Comment: where filterSelection is my function, right? I tried but still nothing

Comment: $model = $this->getModel('your model name'); 
$item=$model->function of your model($variable);

Answer (score 0):

getModel is defines in the JController class.
instead of

```
$this->getModel('yourmodel');
```

try

```
parent::getModel('yourmodel');
```

show us your code, then we can find the problem quick.